# If $\phi: X \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ is a bounded linear functional, then the image $\phi(X)$ of $\phi$ is either $\{ 0\}$ or $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, lp-spaces, functional-equations

I am not entirely sure how to go about this question.

We have that, if the argument of the linear functional is zero, the linear functional is zero (by the definition), but I am not too sure how to go about the proving wheter the image of a nonzero argument is the real line or not.

Prove or disprove: If $\phi: X \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ is a bounded linear functional, then the image $\phi(X)$ of $\phi$ is either $\{ 0\}$ or $\mathbb{R}$.

My way of thinking was let $X = l_1$ and then let us use the sequence $x= (1, \frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{4}, ..., \frac{1}{2^n})$. Then, because our linear functional is bounded, it must be the case that $|f(x)|\leq 2C$, where C is a constant. However, then we have the image is not the real line but the interval between $[-2C,2C]$. Is this a decent proof or am I barking up the wrong tree?

Comment: A linear functional is a linear map between vector spaces. The image of a linear map is a vector subspace of the target space.

Comment: The mistake in your proof is that you only checked $\phi(x)$ for a specific $x\in X$, while you needed to check the whole image $\phi(X)$.

Comment: @treedetective, so if I make x \in l1 arbitrary then it should provide an okay disapproval by counterexample?

Comment: @CatherineDrysdale why are you trying to disprove the statement?  That is, why are you looking for a counterexample?

Comment: Note that 
$$
\phi(X) = \{\phi(x): x \in X\}
$$
we should be looking at what happens to **all** vectors in $X$.

Comment: ah, so the image of a bounded linear functional is the real line? That doesn't make sense surely because |f(x)|< C||x|| for whatever normed space we have?

Comment: It won't give you a counterexample, because you only know that $|\phi(x)|\leq \|\phi\|=C$, for $x\in B_X$. For $x$ not in the ball, $|\phi(x)|$ will  exceed $C$. Instead of trying to find a counterexample try to prove that the claim is true. You just need $\phi$ to be linear as Lord Shark mentioned.

Comment: In the inequality $|f(x)|\leq C\|x\|$, the right side goes to infinity as the norm of $x$ increases,  so you don't get any common upper bound for all $x\in X$.

Comment: ah thank you so much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a proof of the statement: suppose that $\phi(X) \neq 0 $.  That is, suppose that there is some $x \in X$ such that $\phi(x) \neq 0$.  For any $r \in \Bbb R$, note that
$$
\phi\left(\frac{r}{\phi(x)} x\right) = \frac{r}{\phi(x)}\phi(x) = r
$$
It follows that $r \in \phi(X)$.  So, if $\phi(X) \neq 0$, then $\phi(X) = \Bbb R$.

Answer (score 3):

The image of a linear map is a subspace. What are the subspaces of $\mathbb{R}$?

You don't even need $\phi$ is bounded, which is what took you astray.